# Returns the total number of words in the text of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames

I am using Python 3 and I am trying to write a function that takes a filename as an argument and returns the total number of words in the text of that file. I keep getting the error "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'closes'" and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`file.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) instead

Comment: it should be `file.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are referencing an invalid function. `file.closes()` should be `file.close()`